# "Could not find main class" error running TestNG script in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run a Selenium Web-Driver TestNG script in Eclipse. I am getting the error shown below.

[image: TestNG run error]

I have tried changing preferences, checking/unchecking "use project testNG jar", messing with the build path, and recreating the project. Can anyone please help me solve this problem so I can continue creating awesome scripts using TestNG?

Comment: Usually the message in red, this case ending in `ClassLoader.loadClass` is more informative than the red crosses... But it looks like a version conflicts... check your gradle conf

Comment: Gradle conf? What is that?

Comment: My bad, misread Groovy for Gradle (off-topic, something to look into (or maven), reason for me to stick to Java)... But... Can you run it again, kill the pop-ups, scroll the red log upwards, and check to see whether you've got: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`?

Comment: "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/TestNG : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"
So yes I have that (sorry it won't let me use block quotes for some reason).

Comment: See answer, I'm always a bit unsure on the error of wrong version, where the version is referring to, the lib of your version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, based on `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` is wrong Java version. The library you are using is compiled in one version, and you are using a different one (most probably, or definitely) you are using a lower version.

Version 51.0 refers to Java 7. I'd say the library you are using is Java 7 and yours is lower... To change this, go to:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler
```

And set the `Compiler compliance level` higher, at least `1.7` (i.e. Java 7). If that's not an option, install a newer Java JDK (pref 1.8, that can, if you wish, also compile to Java 7).

**Unsupported major.minor version 5{1,2,..}.0**
(copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/928952)

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

**A more elaborative explanation of updating the JDK Eclipse is using:**

> project -> properties -> java build path-> Add Library  -> JRE System
>   Library-> Installed JREs -> Add(unless jdk* is already in the list,
>   then select that and go to next post -> standard VM -> Directory
>   button -> browse to the location where you installed the JDK. Inside
>   that directory you see a couple of folders, including bin and lib. 
>   Make sure you select the parent
>   directory of them. Click OK. You'll then see a list of .jars under JRE
>   system libraries (must!) -> hit finish. Select the checkbox next to
>   jdk1.8*. Press OK then finish. 
>   Now you've got the right Java version
>   in the Build Path... Now we have to make sure that becomes the
>   compiler Now we're back at the properties, Go to Java Compiler, make
>   sure enable project specific settings is turned off. Click Configure
>   Workspace Settings.... set the Compliance level: 1.8 -> apply (you get
>   a message on compiler settings changed rebuild blablabla hit yes) then
>   ok, then ok again...

**Eclipse is given strange error on not finding libs**

> You can try deleting the .project and .classpath files in the root of
>   your project. Delete the project from workspace (don't delete your
>   source, backup first)... then reimport the project... might be that
>   eclipse has configured something that doesn't exist anymore... helps
>   me fix some dubious errors...

Comment: My Compiler compliance level was set at 1.6 and it says the version of my installed JDK is also 1.6. Is this the problem? Should I update my JDK?

Comment: When I go to my Start Menu and search for "Java" and click "About Java", it says I have version 1.7. Why does Eclipse say I have JDK 1.6 installed?

Comment: Does it say `Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.6``or 1.7? If 1.6 go to `Java Build Path` -> `add library` if the workspace is wrong/old browse `Execution environment` first, if it's not in there, go to `Installed JREs` -> `Add` browse to the location your `JDK` (not JRE!) is installed. Othewise, select 1.7 (or 1.8) from the dropdown button

Comment: I didn't notice your first comment. If you can first the 1.7 you can use that. Although I recommend downloading 1.8 JDK anyways... Because it has some nice features - IMHO. See (when you finished this of course ;-)) http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Quiet-Features (I saw I don't know all of them o_O, better start learning :-) )

Comment: Where would I see Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.6`? Also when I go to "Installed JREs" and click "Add" and "Execution Environment Description", I go to my Java folder but cannot find a file with a .ee extension. Where should I be pointing this?

Comment: The basedir is the directory where you also see bin and lib... window preferences java then build path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84608/discussion-between-james4701-and-danielson).